# I want to color HTML table rows based on regex and condition

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have an 'order' table where the first column is the ID of orders. I want to set the `background-color` dependent on the last number of the ID column.

For example, if the Id is `23433` I want to be the color to be `#adcbe3`. I've tried the code below, but it's not working.

```js
$(function() {
  $("tr").each(function() {
    var firstCol = $("tr").find("td:first");
    var reg1 = new RegExp("^[0-9]*[0369]$", 'g');
    var reg2 = new RegExp("^[0-9]*[147]$", 'g');
    var reg3 = new RegExp("^[0-9]*[258]$", 'g');
    if (String(firstCol).match(/^[0-9]*[0369]$/)) {
      $(this).addClass('row1'); //the selected class colors the row green//
    } else if (String(firstCol).match(/^[0-9]*[147]$/)) {
      $(this).addClass('row2');
    } else if (String(firstCol).match(/^[0-9]*[258]$/)) {
      $(this).addClass('row3');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.row1 {
  background: #adcbe3;
}

.row2 {
  background: #e7eff6;
}

.row3 {
  background: #d0e1f9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please include your html?

Comment: Can clarify the following, you mentioned you want the background-color to change based on the last number of the table. So if the id field is 23433 and is the last, then it should be  #adcbe3? Or anywhere where the id 23433 is, it should be #adcbe3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because the `firstCol` variable contains an entire jQuery object. From the context of your question it appears that you expect this to be the innerText of the `td` you select. In which case you need to use `text()`.

In addition you need to use the `this` keyword within the `each()` loop to refer to the current `tr` only. Your current logic would add the class to *every* `tr` in the DOM.

```js
$(function() {
  $("tr").each(function() {
    var firstCol = $(this).find("td:first").text();
    if (firstCol.match(/^[0-9]*[0369]$/)) {
      $(this).addClass('row1');
    } else if (firstCol.match(/^[0-9]*[147]$/)) {
      $(this).addClass('row2');
    } else if (firstCol.match(/^[0-9]*[258]$/)) {
      $(this).addClass('row3');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.row1 { background: #adcbe3; }
.row2 { background: #e7eff6; }
.row3 { background: #d0e1f9; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td>23433</td></tr>
  <tr><td>23434</td></tr>
  <tr><td>23435</td></tr>
  <tr><td>23436</td></tr>
  <tr><td>23444</td></tr>
</table>
```

Alternatively you can make the logic more succinct by using a Regex to validate that the Id is a purely numerical value and then using `slice()` to take its last character to apply the relevant class, something like this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('tr').addClass(function() {
    let id = $(this).find('td:first').text();
    return !id.match(/^[0-9]+$/) ? null : 'row' + ((parseInt(id.slice(-1), 10) || 0) % 3 + 1);
  });
});
```

```css
.row1 { background: #adcbe3; }
.row2 { background: #e7eff6; }
.row3 { background: #d0e1f9; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td>23433</td></tr>
  <tr><td>23434</td></tr>
  <tr><td>23435</td></tr>
  <tr><td>foo</td></tr>
  <tr><td>23436</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's not okay, because  23433 and 23444 is the same color.

Comment: No it isn't, as you can see from the edit I just made to the question

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a regex at all - all you are doing is applying a class based on a grouping of each number with a spread of 3 and this can be determined by the modulus operator.

Note that there are three rows that are different and onw row that is replicated.

All you have to do is to get the text of the first column, get the last character of that and because your grouping the items the way you are - the class can be applied through the modulus of 3. The final addition of 1 is purely because the numbers are zero-indexed but your classes are 1-indexed (the first row is row1 not row0).

```js
$(function() {
  $("tr").each(function() {
    var firstCol = $(this).find("td").first().text();
    var lastChar = firstCol.charAt(firstCol.length-1);
    var index = (parseInt(lastChar) % 3)+1;
    $(this).addClass('row'+ index)
  });
});
```

```css
.row1 {
  background: #adcbe3;
}

.row2 {
  background: #e7eff6;
}

.row3 {
  background: #d0e1f9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
  <tr><td>23430</td></tr>
  <tr><td>23431</td></tr>
  <tr><td>23432</td></tr>
  <tr><td>23433</td></tr>
  <tr><td>23434</td></tr>
  <tr><td>23435</td></tr>
  <tr><td>23436</td></tr>
  <tr><td>23437</td></tr>
  <tr><td>234338</td></tr>
  <tr><td>23439</td></tr>
  <tr><td>23433</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Well => `:first` selector is deprecated since jQuery 3.4. You definitely do not need to use that at all. Use `.first` instead.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping - thanks for that - I was just following what the OP had - but will update to your suggestion. Thanks